# lxd host shows high memory usage not equal to the sum of lxc guest usage

Tags: 20.04, ram, lxd, container

I just want to understand with my lxd host shows high memory usage (more than 80%) while the sum of all guest container memory is way less than that?

```
host:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi        25Gi       2.1Gi       374Mi       3.3Gi       4.7Gi
Swap:          15Gi        96Mi        14Gi

container1# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.8G        209M        3.4G        114M        171M        3.6G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

container2# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       353Mi        30Gi          0B       364Mi        30Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

container3# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       283Mi        30Gi       185Mi       376Mi        30Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

container4# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          5.7Gi       1.7Gi       3.9Gi       0.0Ki       141Mi       4.0Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

container5# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       4.3Gi        26Gi        57Mi       900Mi        26Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

container6# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5.7G        300M        5.3G         13M        100M        5.4G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

There is no other services that run on the host except lxd, ssh, nginx (as a proxy), fail2ban.

Any idea?

Comment: The "used" category does not mean "currently in use by applications." Linux memory management is more complex than that.

Comment: Ok, but is there a risk the host ram get filled up?

Comment: Why would "*the host ram gets filled up*" be a problem? The RAM is there, what's wrong with using it?

Comment: I think what Sebastien is saying @user535733 is that the host RAM is close to being full even though the containers are running very little RAM. So firstly, why is the host RAM saying it's full. Is it a reporting error and it's not really full, or are the containers using more RAM than what is being reported inside the container. I'm facing the same issue. Host has 64GB of RAM. One container says it's using 5GB of RAM, the second is 20GB. Host is reporting 50GB used. Nothing else running. So why do the numbers not balance?

Comment: Why the numbers don't balance most commonly is explained in the answer below. However, if you believe that you have discovered a real problem (like a memory leak), then take a look at https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/4769 for an example of how to report and troubleshoot a suspected LXD memory leak, and the reporting required for an LXD engineer to get involved.

Answer (score 1):

The `free` command is not appropriate to check the memory consumption. There is an added detail that depending on the version of `lxcfs` that is part of your LXD package, some aspects of memory may or may not be abstracted from the containers. See [the available versions of `lxcfs` and their features](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxcfs/news/).

I suggest to use instead `systemd-cgtop` or any of the other `*top` utilities that have support for *cgroups*.